# How to pass Void parameter with pointer from Java and how to write JNI for this?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a function name of the Native program which accepts a void pointer as one parameter

```
int HelloWorld(void *,int);
```

How to write JNI for this CPP method? Also, how to pass Void parameter with pointer from Java? Please help

Answer (score 0):

A `Void` is notionally a wrapper for a `void` type.

If you look at ByteBuffer, it uses a `long` address which becomes a `jlong` in C which can be cast to a pointer of your choosing.  This is only appropriate if you don't expect to be able to access the contents of the pointer in Java.

If you do, Using a ByteBuffer to make the data visible in Java may be an option. (but it is a hack all the same)